# Make single bar in highcharts the width of the container

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart using a stacked bar. the container is 400px wide x 20px height, but I can't seem to get the bar to extend to 100% of the container.

There will only ever be one bar.

You can see the remaining part of the container as there is a light blue background colour (see jsfiddle).

How can i force the width of the bar to 100% of the container?

http://jsfiddle.net/SDK9X/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer. I changed the stacking property to 'percent'.  It was previously 'normal'

```
plotOptions: {
         series: {
            stacking: 'percent', // 'normal'
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
         }
      },
```